# Create a new Course with Google Apps Script - ClassRoom API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

There is an error on line 11 stating:

> Requested entity was not found. (line 11, file "Code")

### line 11

```
createdCourse = Classroom.Courses.get('Bio10');
```

The function:

```
function createA_NewCourse() {
  var courseNew,createdCourse;

  courseNew = Classroom.newCourse();

  courseNew.name = "10th Grade Biology";
  courseNew.id = "Bio10";

  Logger.log("course.name " + courseNew.name);//Verify that name was set

  createdCourse = Classroom.Courses.get('Bio10');//Try to get course by ID

  Logger.log(createdCourse)
}
```

How is a new course created in Apps Script?

Comment: Where are you committing the changes? Shouldn't there be `create()` call to make a new course or a `patch()` or `commit()` to commit the changes you make in lines 5 & 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Dean Ransevycz, there should be a `create()` method.

Here's a sample code:

```
function createCourses() {

  var course;
  course = Classroom.newCourse();       

  course.name = "10th Grade Biology";
  course.ownerId = "me";
  //course.id = "Bio10";

  course = Classroom.Courses.create(course);
  Logger.log('%s (%s)', course.name, course.id);

  var list = Classroom.Courses.list();
  Logger.log(list);

}
```

[image]

You're getting an `Requested entity was not found.` error since you might be using the wrong course id. And I guess you can't set an ID when creating a course. [(Source.)](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-courses#create_a_course)

Answer (score 0):

There are specific values for the `ownerId` that must be used.  The `ownerId` specifies the owner of the course.  One of the valid `ownerId` strings is "me" which is the requesting user.

Other valid owner ID strings are:

- the numeric identifier for the user
- the email address of the user

The email address of the user is self explanatory.  I don't know where you get the numeric identifier of the user.

Without the `ownerId` setting being set first, or being set to an invalid string, I was getting an error message:

> The caller does not have permission